# Why am I getting just table's field names but data in csv file?

Tags: c#

Why am I getting just table's field names but data in csv file ? I wrote below c# code:

```
private string GetConnectionString()
{
    return @"Data Source=BLC-LT-26\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Quality;Integrated Security=True;";
}
private string GetCSV()
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BLC-LT-26\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Quality;Integrated Security=True;");
    {
        cn.Open();
        return CreateCSV(new SqlCommand("select SNumber, Jnumber from J0_118 ", cn).ExecuteReader());

    }
}

private string CreateCSV(IDataReader reader)
{
    string file = @"C:\\CSV\\ExportedData.csv";
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    string headerLine = "";
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        string[] columns = new string[reader.FieldCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            columns[i] = reader.GetName(i);
        }
        headerLine = string.Join(",", columns);
        lines.Add(headerLine);
    }
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
        reader.GetValues(values);
        lines.Add(string.Join(",", values));
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);

    return file;
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: How many rows are present actually in your J0_118 table? Do you have just one line of data? (1 record)

Comment: Yes, I have just one record in the table.

Comment: Then your problem is that you call reader.Read() to create the header, but at this point you have already the first row in the reader. So the next reader.Read() return false. Change the first reader.Read() in reader.HasRows

Comment: *getting just table's field names but data* - what do you mean? Do you mean *but no data*? Please edit your question and clarify it.

Comment: Thanks Steve! But when I change that to reader.HasRows then I get an error message. Seems like reader does not has property.

Comment: Yes, the IDataReader interface has no HasRows declared, you should pass an SqlDataReader instead. See my answer below.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `Read()` method of a `DataReader` loads the first record (if it exists) into the internal buffer and prepares the reader to load the next record. Calling again `Read()` loads the second record (if it exists)

In your code you use the `reader.Read()` a first time and then try to prepare the header for the CSV and then the code enters a while loop to read the data. But this logic causes the code to skip the first record and, of course, if there is only one record it causes the return of just the column' names

To fix, you should change the GetCSV method signature and declare the parameter to be an `SqlDataReader`, then instead of using `reader.Read()` to check if there are records you could check the `reader.HasRows` property

```
private string CreateCSV(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    string file = @"C:\\CSV\\ExportedData.csv";
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    string headerLine = "";
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        string[] columns = new string[reader.FieldCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            columns[i] = reader.GetName(i);
        }
        headerLine = string.Join(",", columns);
        lines.Add(headerLine);
    }
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
        reader.GetValues(values);
        lines.Add(string.Join(",", values));
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
    return file;
}
```

But still I don't understand why you want to write the column names only if there are records. I would write them in any case. Just a header line will be present in the file if the recordset is empty.

Comment: Awesome Steve! It works fine. Appreciate the help!